# When selecting a button -- Error: [$parse:lexerr]

Tags: angularjs

### What is this error message and what does it indicate?

I get the following error message when selecting a button on a web application:

> Error: [$parse:lexerr] https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/docs/error/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2074-78%20%5B%22%7D%27)%5D&p2=vm.initSource(%27%7B%22BaseId%22:1127,%22Basename%22:%22Chaul%20End%20Lane%20Children%27s%20Centre%22%7D

Image can also be seen below:

[image: Angular error message]

When I visit the following URL:

https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/docs/error/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%2074-78%20%5B%22%7D%27)%5D&p2=vm.initSource(%27%7B%22BaseId%22:1127,%22Basename%22:%22Chaul%20End%20Lane%20Children%27s%20Centre%22%7D

It states the error occurs when an expression has a lexical error, for example a malformed number (0.5e-) or an invalid unicode escape.. What does this mean?

I'm a rookie so any advise will be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Please don't post error codes as images, copy them as text instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error explanation is quite clear:

> Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 74-78 ["}')] in expression [vm.initSource('{"BaseId":1127,"Basename":"Chaul End Lane Children's Centre"}].

Ending quote is missing `'` from the string parameter

Comment: Thank you for your help!